# Free energy difference between change in protein structure and its reverse?

Tags: protein-folding, energy

I have seen in many articles that a protein variation (A- > B) and its reverse (B- > A) must have the opposite value of the free energy difference (ΔΔGAB = − ΔΔGBA).

But i’ve alse heard that in experimental data this is not true!
So i am a little bit confused; can anyone explain it? Which is the case?

Comment: Welcome to Biology StackExchange! The Gibbs free energy $G$ is a [state function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/State_function), hence the free energy difference of the reversal process $\ce{B->A}$ has the opposite value of the forward process $\ce{A->B}$, $\Delta G_{\ce{B->A}} = -\Delta G_{\ce{A->B}}$. Please **edit you question** and **include references** (articles, books ...) where they state that this is not true. Otherwise, we cannot know what exactly they mean, and also cannot give you any meaningful answer.

Comment: I have modified your title to indicate the type of “variation” you seem to be referring to on the basis of one of your tags. But you should make this clear in your question, or if this is incorrect say precisely what you mean. “Protein Variation” could mean many things, and protein folding would not be on my list.